# MFMessageComposeViewController make the app reload after close?

Tags: swift, sms

i have table of contacts , the logic user will multi select contacts to send them sms invite to the app , my issue is after popup sms compose( when close or send ) the composer is closed and the app is been restarted, is it how its work? why it should reset the app i am just closing or canceling the sms compose controller !

here is what i did

```
//Send SMS
func sendSMS( to : [String] = [] , message : String = "" )
{

     if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText())
     {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = message
            controller.recipients = to

            if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController()
            {
                controller.messageComposeDelegate = topController as MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
                topController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    }
}

    extension UIViewController: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {


        public func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
            switch (result.rawValue) {
            case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
                print("Message was cancelled")
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
                print("Message failed")
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
                print("Message was sent")
                controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

is there anyway to close sms composer without reloading the app ?

Comment: Are you getting an error message (crash)? Are you running on the simulator? I don't think sending messages works on the simulator so that could cause issues.

Comment: its not crashing , when dismiss the sending message its reloading the app